# Bootstrap Tooltip Following Animated Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

I have a D3.js chart similar to [this](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html). As the user drills down into the chart I utilize the bootstrap tooltip to display the nodes name.  I am currently tracking the node by call the tooltip show method over and over which cause the tooltip to re-render at the new location.

```
setInterval(function(){
        $(node).tooltip('show');
    }, 100)
```

My concern is that calling this function like this will cause performance issues.  Can anyone suggest a better way to accomplish this or give me some insights on to performance issues when using the setInterval function this way?

Answer (score 0):

From your description it sounds like what you are trying to do would be better accomplished by listening for discrete changes in state rather than time.  I haven't worked with D3.js, but even something as simple as listening for clicks on `<circle>` elements would be a ton more efficient.

### JS

```
$('svg').on('click', 'circle', function () {
  $(node).tooltip('show')
})
```

It looks like [D3.js has it's own event framework](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-on), but I'm not sure if it supports delegation.  Someone more familiar could probably provide a better suggestion to that end.

Finally, depending on how many nodes you show at once, calling tooltip show on *all* of them could itself generate a performance hit.  Tracking which ones open and close each time by storing references could be more efficient.  Again, there might be something already in **D3.js** to handle this, but it's not something I know.

Comment: Each tooltip is initiated by a click event on the circle element and I am also storing the interval id in the data for the node so that the interval function can be killed when the node is rolled up.

Comment: @Bryce Hmm...it'd really help if you could post a JSFiddle or Plunk example.